# Using Complex IF Statement in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement

Hi i'm trying to write If statement in Band Attribute but without Success T_T. what Im trying to do is have single Character A, B, C, D depending on the owner_category, Sheds and Water_Supply attribute. Any Help will be Great ^^.

```
CREATE TABLE Rent_Band
(
    Plot_ID NUMBER(3),
    Band VARCHAR(1)
    IF SELECT * FROM Rent_Band WHERE Owner_Category = 'Council' AND WHERE Sheds ='No' THEN Band ='A'
    ELSE IF SELECT * FROM Rent_Band WHERE Owner_Category = 'Private' AND WHERE  Water_Supply ='Yes' THEN Band ='D'
    ELSE IF SELECT * FROM Rent_Band WHERE Owner_Category = 'Council' AND WHERE  Water_Supply ='No' AND WHERE Sheds ='Yes' THEN Band ='B'
    ELSE IF SELECT * FROM Rent_Band WHERE Owner_Category = 'Private' AND WHERE Water_Supply ='No' AND WHERE Sheds ='No' THEN Band ='B'
    ELSE THEN Band = 'C',
    Rent_Charge NUMBER(4), 
    Owner_Category VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT Checking_Owner_Category CHECK((Owner_Category='Private') OR (Owner_Category='Council')), 
    Sheds VARCHAR(3) CHECK((Sheds='Yes') OR (Sheds='No')), 
    Water_Supply VARCHAR(3) CHECK((Water_Supply='Yes') OR (Water_Supply='No'))
)
```

Comment: yes that is a SQL Server

Comment: Pleae be specific when identifying the server software - "SQL Server" is almost universally identified as Microsoft SQL Server, not Oracle

Comment: its oracle 11g yhea thanks 4 the tip n yhea sorry this is my first time in forum and new to this sql business :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF54376) on virtual columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Rent_Band
(
    Plot_ID NUMBER(3),
    Band VARCHAR(1) AS
       (CASE WHEN Owner_Category = 'Council' AND Sheds ='No' THEN 'A'
            WHEN Owner_Category = 'Private' AND Water_Supply ='Yes' THEN 'D'
            WHEN Owner_Category = 'Council' AND Water_Supply ='No' AND Sheds ='Yes' THEN 'B'
            WHEN Owner_Category = 'Private' AND Water_Supply ='No' AND Sheds ='No' THEN 'B'
       ELSE 'C' END),
    Rent_Charge NUMBER(4), 
    Owner_Category VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT Checking_Owner_Category CHECK((Owner_Category='Private') OR (Owner_Category='Council')), 
    Sheds VARCHAR(3) CHECK((Sheds='Yes') OR (Sheds='No')), 
    Water_Supply VARCHAR(3) CHECK((Water_Supply='Yes') OR (Water_Supply='No'))
)
```

BTW, I would STRONGLY recommend:

- using a `bit` field instead of a `Yes`/`No` constraint for `Sheds` and `Water_Supply` (saves room and overhead checking constraints, and translates directly to boolean in most app languages)
- using a lookup table for `Owner_Category` instead of a string constraint for basically the same reasons

Comment: i though i was running sql server but it turns out i was doing it on oracle 11g and this code you gave me gave me an error sorry, my mistake

Comment: Updated my answer - added parens around the CASE statement.  Should work now.

Comment: thank you sir that worked!! and do you want a chocolate cookie :)